# Spigot algorithm derived from Bellard's formula (pi)

Tags: algorithm, math, pi

I have been working on a program to calculate Pi to the nth digit and currently have the [BBP formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BBPFormula.html) implemented efficiently. I was told that Bellard's formula was 43% faster so I wanted to give that a try. After researching the formula I have heard reference to but can't derive a working spigot algorithm from the formula. Could someone explain how to get the spigot algorithm from a formula?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic; it belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could you post what you've tried, and then I reckon we'll see clearer how SO might help! Thanks.

Comment: did you look at bellard's technical notes (http://bellard.org/pi/pi2700e9/pipcrecord.pdf)?